# could not load 'CKFinder.Connector.Connec'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, ckeditor, ckfinder

I have them in **Ckfinder** and **Ckeditor** folders. When I click on the image icon to insert an image on the editor, then click "Browse Server", it opens the popup with the "file browser" but I get an error message giving a Server response status 500 parse error message could not load type **'CKFinder.Connector.Connector'**

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Answer (score 0):

From the [ckeditor](https://ckeditor.com/old/forums/Support/Could-not-load-type-CKFinder.Connector.Connector) forum, it says that you need to make sure the dll is in the bin folder.

> Make sure that CKFinder.dll file is located straight inside of "bin" folder.
>   By default CKFinder's bin folder contains subfolders "Release" and "Debug".

[As stated here](https://ckeditor.com/old/forums/Support/internal-server-error-500), if you add the `CKFinder.dll` in your references, it should solve the problem, without you having to manually copy it.